# Javascript - Can not access array elements of an array created from a csv file

Tags: javascript, arrays, csv, d3.js

I need to put data from a csv file which is generated by a database into an array. I downloaded the file and put it into the same folder as the script.

The csv file is formatted like this: (Unfortunately I can not show the original data)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/SgKt1.png

[image]

I found the d3 script which I used to import the data from the csv file.
My code to import it looks like this:

```
var myArray= []

d3.csv("data.csv", function(data){
    myArray.push(data)
});

console.log(myArray)
```

So, now I can show the array in console with the console command "myArray".
Looks like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZA7Tw.png

[image]

When I open the array I can see serveral objects which are formatted like this:

```
0: { "HeaderA": "A1", "HeaderB": "B1", "HeaderC": "C1", … }

1: { "HeaderA": "A2", "HeaderB": "B2", "HeaderC": "C2", … }

2: { "HeaderA": "A3", "HeaderB": "B3", "HeaderC": "C3", … }
```

and so on...

My problems:

1. When I type `myArray[0]` in console I can see the first object (0 - like above) but I can not access the elements inside (A1,B1,C1...) Why?/How?
2. I can not type `myArray[0]` into my code to for example loop through the objects. I get the Error Message: **"ReferenceError: array is not defined"**
3. **I need to format the array like this...**

```
[["HeaderA", "A1", "A2", "A3", "A4" "A5"],
 ["HeaderB", "B1", "B2", "B3", "B4" "B5"],["HeaderC", "C1", "C2", "C3", "C4" "C5"],...]
```

**...to work with the data.
I have no idea how I could do this since I cannot access the single elements?**

Thank You :)

Comment: Is there any reason for having such a format to work with (point 3)? is that a d3.js requirement?

Comment: @briosheje My objective is to read data from a html table. At first I just pasted the html table into the html file i work in, found a jquery script to format it like point 3 and sort it my elements.(Now I have the data structured to my needs) After I've done this I noticed that there is also a csv file available. So now I need to get an array what fits this format to extract the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably neither the fastest, nor the most efficient solution, but here is what you can do to get the desired format, splitted in various steps:

- Make a **set** of unique keys, so that you will be aware of what keys you will need to use.
- Map the above keys and get, from the original array, all the values for that key.

Assuming a sample input like this:

```
var parsedArray = [
    { "HeaderA": "A1", "HeaderB": "B1", "HeaderC": "C1" },
    { "HeaderA": "A2", "HeaderB": "B2", "HeaderC": "C2" },
    { "HeaderA": "A3", "HeaderB": "B3", "HeaderC": "C3" }
];
```

(taking inspiration from your example), here is the code to get the desired format:

```
const uniqueKeys = [...new Set(...parsedArray.map(i => Object.keys(i)))];

const res = uniqueKeys.map(k => {
    return [k, ...parsedArray.map(i => i[k]).filter(i => i !== null && i !== undefined)];
});
console.log(res);
```

Explained:

```
[...new Set(...parsedArray.map(i => Object.keys(i)))];
```

The spread operator (...) is used to spread the values, since arrays are iterable. the `map` inside it will collect **all the keys** of the objects (HeaderA, HeaderB, HeaderC) and so on. `new Set` will make the array **unique**, so that duplicates will be removed. You will end up with an array like: `["HeaderA","HeaderB","HeaderC"]`.

About the second part, the return statement creates a new array **for each unique key**, returning as the first element the header itself, and will add, as array values, all the elements in the original array whose key is the **currently looped key**.

Working fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/jde37v64/1/

As a side note, the values are written asynchronously in your callback, so you should do this:

```
var myArray= []

d3.csv("data.csv", function(data){
    myArray.push(data)
    console.log(myArray)
    // Write your code here, NOT OUTSIDE OF THIS FUNCTION BLOCK.
});
```

Otherwise you won't be able to use `myArray`, since it's available only inside the callback.

Comment: Is there a better way to get that array format directly from the csv file? (Maybe import it in another way?

Comment: No, CSV are supposed to work like that, it's actually correct that the data is acquired in this way ;)

Comment: Okay thank you thats the format I needed! But now I have over 40 arrays but I only need the last one.(The last one is complete and the other arrays are the same array but with less elements) Is there a way to only have the array which is complete? Why does it output the other arrays? Thanks for your help :)

Comment: What do you mean by "complete"? the above code will look for all the CSV values, do you need to filter only the values having **all** the keys? may you please provide an example in the fiddle above so that I may be able to properly help you? Ideally, you should provide an easier example showing the problematic as you did above (input, current output, expected output)

Comment: And one more question. Is there a way to store the array so I can use it outside the callback?

Comment: Yes, there is, but you need to keep in mind of sync and async operations. You need to ensure that the array is defined and filled. In fact, it is available everywhere, but it will hold values only **afther** the callback of `.csv` is fired. Once again, if you provide in the same fiddle an example of where you need to use it, I can give you some hints about how to do it.

Comment: Could we chat over there?: https://jsfiddle.net/jde37v64/1/#&togetherjs=7TeIrjoUrF

Comment: I Currently can't chat, I will be available later today, if you can prepare the fiddle, I will check this later :)

Comment: @House97_ I've added some examples in this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6trj9yq4/ . If you need further help, feel free to mail me :)